# How do I start supporting a custom handler method response type in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I oftentimes want to return an Object as response body which is not supported by spring. So Instead I do:

```java
public HttpEntity<?> doStuff() {
  MyClass myObject = ... ;
  return SomeHelper.toHttpEntity(myObject);
}
```

While this works, it is uncool, because it makes my code less testable and adds the same call over and over to various handler methods. Thus I wonder if I could add support for an additional type in spring.

I couldn't find anything on Google, but reading through the source code I found the interface `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` whose implementors do the conversion. So I'd implement that interface for my custom type, but how do I register it (using XML) in spring?

Comment: Maybe your configuration is messed up? What is your desired response content type? Json? Xml? I always do `public MyClass doStuff()` to render Json without `HttpEntity`. The only premise is Jackson for Json or Jaxb for Xml on classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need your own `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, but just in case:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:return-value-handlers>
    <bean class="my.own.Handler" />
  </mvc:return-value-handlers>
```

If `mvc` is your default namepsace you omit the qualifier, of course.